# Content hosted by github pages doesn't show up perfectly

Tags: github, openweathermap, freegeoip

I was experimenting with github after building a little webapp as a project for free code camp. After hosting it on github pages it shows up broken. Most of its content is blocked. This is the link https://mojojojo77.github.io/ 
On mozila it says that the connection is secure but "firefox has blocked parts of this page which are not secure." I looked into the console for the problem and the API's I used seem to be cause. Is there a way to bypass this ? Like asking the user for permissions.

Comment: I'm actually not seeing any error messages, in Firefox or Chrome. Perhaps it has to do with a firewall setting? Maybe see if anyone else is able to access it, outside of your network?

Comment: I tried, still some part of the website doesn't load properly.

Comment: @OshoSArAF, were you able to get this working using the answer below?

Comment: @Chris After doing a bit of a research I found out that the API I used was using the http not the https protocol which [Blocked loading mixed active content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content) and a problem with the CORS [No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is present on the requested resource] (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS). The below solution worked fine until I hosted it on the Github. As a quick fix I used a [CORS proxy]  (https://crossorigin.me/) which solved both of my problems.

Comment: @Chris If you have a better solution, let me know

Comment: @OshoSArAF, I'm glad you found a solution to your problem. Please consider [answering your own question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-if-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking) and then accepting it if you feel it is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Load your resources using a [`//` protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Protocol-relative_URL) instead of `http://` or `https://`. That will cause the browser to request resources using a protocol that matches the page (using SSL if the page does, and not if it doesn't).